Me sale este error "Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property" como podria solucionar

Este error es visible desde la consola de cchrome

Bienvenida, agrega como texto el error, ya que puede no ser visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad.

Para solucionarlo, asigna a la variable foo un objeto que si tenga la propiedad bar. Pero ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?
